# Need CSS Dropdown Menu Advice

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, hover

I am trying to make my first pure css/html dropdown menu but I was having a hard time getting the Hover function to work properly. I received great answers but this time, its all messed up and its not in the right spot. I am so lost at this point.

http://jsfiddle.net/X5Dbc/

```
    position: absolute; or somthing like that...
```

i have a hunch it has somthing to do with `positioning`
the jsfiddle above is what i have after asking about the "Dropdown" effect..

Keep in mind I am still a novice when it comes to proper CSS. Any Advice or help making this menu work would be most appreciated! And constructive criticism is always welcome.

Comment: Instead of doing "ul[id=drop]" do "ul#drop" :)

Comment: oh, ok. that would be the cleaner method. thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your markup is not valid. `ID`s must be unique. ie you can't use the same `ID` on muiltiple elements. That's what `class` is for. There is no need to use `ID`s for this anyway.

```
#navwrap ul li ul {
    display: none;
}
#navwrap ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
```

Move the `:hover` to the parent `li`

You can style the two `ul` seperately  like this:

Top level:

```
#navwrap > ul { your styles ... }
```

Sublevel:

```
#navwrap ul ul { your styles ... }
```

Comment: Your answers really helped. Thank you much